# IOS 6, crash with low memory warning

Tags: memory, crash, ios6, memory-leaks

My apps, after upgrading to IOS 6.0 keeps on crashing. In the console, it shows low memory warning, this won't happen in IOS 4, and IOS 5... I am using ARC. I try to look at the crash report but tell me nothing,here it is

```
=============================================
Incident Identifier: 06CF58AA-4C1A-4CA3-A522-F44881E8D301
CrashReporter Key:   69ed28238a860bdf99a77524c1b4b029516122e1
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 6.0 (10A403)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Sun Aug 19 00:27:34 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2107.2.33~4/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8930X
Date:                2012-10-06 20:57:43 +0800
Time since snapshot: 63 ms

Free pages:        318
Active pages:      1626
Inactive pages:    1057
Throttled pages:   44479
Purgeable pages:   5
Wired pages:       15989
Largest process:   MJClub

Processes
     Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max       [reason]          (state)

      MobileMail <bff817c61ce33c85a43ea9a6c98c29f5>         1053             1053         [vm]         (resume) (continuous)
     MobilePhone <3fca241f2a193d0fb8264218d296ea41>          996              996         [vm]         (resume) (continuous)
            tccd <eb5ddcf533663f8d987d67cae6a4c4ea>          161              161         [vm]         (daemon)
          MJClub <ab7b5723f2023289927f68004c99544b>        17907            17907         [vm]         (frontmost) (resume)
            ptpd <04a56fce67053c57a7979aeea8e5a7ea>          588              588                      (daemon)
    mediaserverd <80657170daca32c9b8f3a6b1faac43a2>          442              442                      (daemon)
         syslogd <cbef142fa0a839f0885afb693fb169c3>          148              148                      (daemon)
      aosnotifyd <d4d14f2914c3343796e447cfef3e6542>          434              434                      (daemon)
     dataaccessd <2a3f6a518f3f3646bf35eddd36f25005>         1347             1347                      (daemon)
   iaptransportd <f784f30dc09d32078d87b450e8113ef6>          213              213                      (daemon)
       locationd <892cd1c9ffa43c99a82dba197be5f09e>          701              701                      (daemon)
           wifid <9472b090746237998cdbb9b34f090d0c>          297              297                      (daemon)
     SpringBoard <27372aae101f3bbc87804edc10314af3>         2462             2462                     
      backboardd <5037235f295b33eda98eb5c72c098858>         3475             3475                      (daemon)
         configd <4245d73a9e96360399452cf6b8671844>          368              368                      (daemon)
   fairplayd.N81 <335829f71dcd315fae46a042918d4716>          145              145                      (daemon)
       fseventsd <996cc4ca03793184aea8d781b55bce08>          317              317                      (daemon)
         imagent <1e68080947be352590ce96b7a1d07b2f>          353              353                      (daemon)
   mDNSResponder <3e557693f3073697a58da6d27a827d97>          204              204                      (daemon)
       lockdownd <ba1358c7a8003f1b91af7d5f58dd5bbe>          266              266                      (daemon)
          powerd <2d2ffed5e69638aeba1b92ef124ed861>          144              144                      (daemon)
  UserEventAgent <6edfd8d8dba23187b05772dcdfc94f90>          431              431                      (daemon)
     debugserver <185719f06f1631d4922c652bdd4c8529>            0                0                      (daemon)
springboardservi <ff6f64b3a21a39c9a1793321eefa5304>            0                0                      (daemon)
    syslog_relay <45e9844605d737a08368b5215bb54426>            0                0                      (daemon)
      DTMobileIS <23303ca402aa3705870b01a9047854ea>            0                0                      (daemon)
    syslog_relay <45e9844605d737a08368b5215bb54426>            0                0                      (daemon)
notification_pro <845b7beebc8538ca9ceef731031983b7>          131              131                      (daemon)
            afcd <b0aff2e7952e34a9882fec81a8dcdbb2>          136              136                      (daemon)
filecoordination <fbab576f37a63b56a1039153fc1aa7d8>          122              122                      (daemon)
       distnoted <a89af76ec8633ac2bbe99bc2b7964bb0>          106              106                      (daemon)
            apsd <94d8051dd5f5362f82d775bc279ae608>          316              316                      (daemon)
        networkd <0032f46009f53a6c80973fe153d1a588>          159              159                      (daemon)
      aggregated <8c3c991dc4153bc38aee1e841864d088>           94               94                      (daemon)
        BTServer <c92fbd7488e63be99ec9dbd05824f5e5>          300              300                      (daemon)
       securityd <dafed6d6d9843902a4a215ae04b0b530>          156              156                      (daemon)
         notifyd <51c0e03da8a93ac8a595442fcaac531f>          155              155                      (daemon)

**End**
===========================================================
```

I don't know much about instrument, but I also take a look at it and here is some data from instrument

By using Activity Monitor

- Virtual Mem=219M
- Real Mem= 32M

By using Allocation

- Live Byte = 2.5M (Crash at around 2.5M)
- By using Leak

No Leak found when take away admob

a little leak found when using admob, but i think it is not significant

By using VMTracker

- Resident Size=82.43MB
- Dirty Size=40MB in the beginning, but increase to 72MB, and keeps on receive low memory warning and crash, if I don't use admob, the apps can run for over 1 hours without any problem.

For admob I am using the latest 6.2.0, I've try to use mediation id/publisher id, both give the same result. using 6.0.1 gives the same  result.

I've also replace admob with other ad(e.g. inmobi) it will last longer, but still crash sometimes (10min from startup)

Please any one can give me any idea on this issue? This crash only happened in IOS6, in IOS5 everything is fine. Once again I am using ARC.

Comment: Getting the same thing on iOS6, but I'm not using ARC

Answer (score 3):

My app using ARC starting leaking memory very badly on iOS6 whilst it ran perfectly on iOS5. When I say "leaking", I actually mean allocating memory and then not releasing the memory properly when I removed objects from mutable arrays, causing the app's memory usage to increase dramatically.

After lots of frustration, I've managed to fix it by setting up an @autoreleasepool { ... } around the offending section.

My suspicion is that iOS6 is threading my app differently compared with iOS5, as there used to be an @autorelease pool covering that process.

I hope that helps someone. Good luck fixing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

By monitoring the memory on my app, I saw that on iOS6 there is less free memory (RAM) available compared to iOS5. I guess iOS6 needs more memory. So, less memory is available for apps and memory warning are more frequent.